# Will Casper affect transaction prices?

Tags: transactions, casper

To what extent will Casper affect transaction prices?

Seems like it wouldn't affect gas amounts, but that it would lower the gas prices, owing to the lower costs of operating the network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a big reason for the push to Casper is lower transaction prices AND lower block times (4 seconds) which will lower prices even more. Since the network is effectively free/very cheap to secure with Proof of Stake, miners (stakes) will not need as large of a reward for their participation.